# C# Error - System.FormatException

Tags: c#

Someone was helping me with another question and gave me a code example that worked great.  I tried tweaking it a bit to write to a file instead of the console and I'm getting the following error:

*System.FormatException:  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime*

The code is as follows:

```
// There is probably a more efficient way to do this...
string[] getFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TestFiles", "*.x12");
string fn = getFiles[0];

string text = File.ReadAllText(fn);

var lines = text.Split('\n');

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("outfile.txt"))
{
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("DTP*348"))
        {
            var elements = line.Split('*');
            var dateString = elements[3];

            var dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
            var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // The error is thrown by this line

            if (date < new DateTime(2014, 06, 01))
            {
                date = new DateTime(2014, 06, 01);
                sw.WriteLine("DTP*" + elements[1] + "*" + elements[2] + "*" + "20140601");
            }
            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that `dateString` does contain a valid date in yyyyMMdd format.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is maybe you aren't trimming whitespace or other characters? I just tested your format string and statement with some sample values, and it worked fine for me. Can you paste the 'exact' value of your `dateString` value?

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger to verify the value when the exception is thrown?

Comment: I figured it out.  There was a trailing \r in the file after the date.  Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a `try{...} catch (exception e){...}` and look at the exception message and stack ?

Comment: I'm new here, what do I do once a question has been resolved?  Do I just leave it or should I delete it?

Comment: @JayDonovan Post an answer to your question below and then accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the text to has no whitespace, pay close attention to any carriage return and line feed characters which are invisible to the naked eye. The string method [Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good function to remove such whitespace.

Comment: I figured it out using Notepad++ to view all characters in the file.  There was a trailing \r after the date.  Thank you.

Comment: According to this I would replace your Split by `var lines = text.Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)` Edit: changed to String.Split, since it is faster

Comment: @Matt `[\r\n]+` will do the same.

Comment: Yes, you're right (it was `\r?\n|\r` before). But I think here is String.Split the better solution anyway.